# How can I refresh the fragment when an button is clicked in an item in android side menu

Tags: android, checkbox, android-fragments, navigation-drawer

I have a checkbox for one of the items in my navigation drawer. On checking it I am setting a preference value to true. In one of my fragments I have a checkbox which is set based on this preference value. Everything works fine except for one case.

That is, when I am on this particular fragment. I open the navigation drawer and check/uncheck this checkbox. Close the drawer. The setting of checkbox is not affecting in my fragment. This is because fragment is not refreshing.

How can I do this?Anyone please help me out. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

put the code inside onResume section of activity and call onresume() wherever you want.

Comment: I am not resuming activity here.

Comment: I say you put that code inside onResume for what you want to refresh your fragment.

Comment: OnResume inside fragment won't be called.